# Получить дату из unix timestamp с timezone

Tags: php

Есть дата в таком формате:

```
$date = '/Date(1668783780000+0100)/';
//08.11.2022 15:13
```

Понимаю, что это какой-то там формат unix timestamp с миллисекундами с указанием часового пояса. Можно ли одной-двумя функциями распарсить дату с преобразованием в мой часовой пояс (+3) или придется распарсивать отдельно timestamp (например регуляркой/filter_var), преобразовывать в дату, ставить мой часовой пояс?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: @u_mulder я видел, но такая конструкция не срабатывает `DateTime::createFromFormat('Uu+O','1668783780000+0100')`

Comment: Так как формата для миллисекунд не завезли, то какие-то костыли придется городить. Заменять например `000+` на `+`, а это уже просто `U+O` (ну или `\d{3}\+` в общем случае).

Comment: @u_mulder именно так и сделал, задал вопрос, так как не знал об этом символе `U`

Comment: @u_mulder как раз миллисекунды завезли, символом `u`, но парсер полагаю не может знать из сколько символов состоит штамп 10 или 13 и парсит число целиком, если стоит любой разделитель, то парсится например маской `U.u`

Comment: Миллисекунды парсятся скорее из времени типа `12:01:12.435`